# A good reference on optimal control theory

Tags: reference-request, control-theory, optimal-control

Ok, so I am reading about decision making and I came across this subject. Fortunately it has a  [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control), but the point is I want to see some examples, and learn to solve regular problems of this field. Of course I can go for the book by Pontryagin but then I don't think that would be an educative book. Does anyone has a suggestion? I would be happy if it also covers LQ problems.

P.S. I studied math, therefore I appreciate a book with rigorous approach to the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good reference is the recent book Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory: A Concise Introduction by Daniel Liberzon http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9760.html

Optimal Control Theory: An Introduction is an older, somewhat more engineering-oriented book, reprinted by Dover Books. It is a good classic.

Start with 1 or 2 of these. Most other texts are heavier reading than both of these together.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0486135071  is the second book, by Kirk (1970, 464p). Also [Walking randomly](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4929) has links on Software for the teaching of (and tinkering with) Control Theory and Control Systems.