# What's a really good book for a course titled "Optimization and Control Theory"?

Tags: reference-request, optimization

I can't seem to find one that shows a lot of examples with the theory. Could I get some help?

Also, it would be a bonus if the book/material is readily available online so I can download it onto my kindle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following all have examples (you can peruse most online to see if they suit your needs):

- Modern Control Theory (3rd Edition), William L. Brogan (it has some intro chapters on Optimal Control and Nonlinear Control, but is full of example and problems for Control Theory)
- Linear Control Theory: Structure, Robustness, and Optimization, Shankar P. Bhattacharyya, Aniruddha Datta, Lee H. Keel
- Optimal Control Theory for Applications (Mechanical Engineering Series), David G. Hull
- Modern Control Engineering (5th Edition), Katsuhiko Ogata

There is even a Schaum's Outline and a Problem Solver (REA) on Automatic Control (not sure they are exactly what you are looking for), but worth perusing to verify.

I cannot imagine that there are not some great notes with examples out there and also some Open Courseware materials.

You can also repuse these previous posts:

- [Control / Feedback Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34322/control-feedback-theory)
- [A good reference on optimal control theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490618/a-good-reference-on-optimal-control-theory)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44015/how-do-i-approach-optimal-control
- http://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/optimal-control

Lastly, you did not ask about Nonlinear Systems or Adaptive Control, so I did not include anything there.

Comment: Excellent post! +1

Comment: @amWhy: thanks, that is one fun topic!